# Why can't I get the correct post permalink

Tags: custom-field, permalinks, taxonomy

I don't think this is the most elegant way of achieving my objective but it's 95% there.

I have created a page template and added a post loop to list custom posts based on the a custom field set on the page.

I am trying to show a list of associated posts. I have a custom taxonomy 'servicestax' containing values such as 'design' and 'support' I want to show the posts for my custom post type 'Services' with a link to the post.

The issue i face is the permalink is output as the current page url and not a post url from the list of custom posts. I don't really understand why this should be as the thumbnail, title and excerpt all appear as expected.

The code I have cobbled together is as follows (I have added too much error checking yet!)

```
 $key_value = get_field('post_types' );
$custom_terms = get_terms('servicestax');
   foreach($custom_terms as $custom_term) {
wp_reset_query();
$args = array('post_type' => 'services',
    'tax_query' => array(
        array(
            'taxonomy' => 'servicestax',
            'field' => 'slug',
            'terms' => $custom_term->slug,
        ),
    ),
 );
if (! empty($key_value)){
if ($custom_term->slug == $key_value->slug){
 $loop = new WP_Query($args);
 if($loop->have_posts()) {
    while($loop->have_posts()) : $loop->the_post(); ?>
    <div class="listing col-md-8">
    <h3><a href="<?php get_post_permalink()?>"><?php the_title()?> </a></h3>
         <div class="col-md-3 col-sm-3 hidden-xs"><img class=" hidden-xs" src=" <?php the_post_thumbnail_url( 'thumbnail' )?>"/></div>
         <div class="col-md-9 col-sm-9">
        <?php the_excerpt() ?>
        <a href="<?php get_post_permalink()?>">more information</a>
        </div>
        </div>
<?php            
    endwhile;
 }   }   }   }
```

Comment: You need `echo get_post_permalink()`, or just `the_permalink()`. You're currently outputting nothing.

Comment: Slightly embarrassing, thank you for spotting such a basic error!

Answer (score 0):

You just need to echo `get_post_permalink()`

```
  <?php echo get_post_permalink();?>
```

Answer (score 0):

`get_post_permalink()` just get the permalink, you need to tell PHP to insert the same there so the use `<?php echo get_post_permalink();?>`